# Cloudflare ssl and proxied mode is not working

Tags: centos, cloudflare, apollo-server

I am hosting Apollo Graphql Node.js server with mariadb on centos 8.

It is only hosting for API server.

So my client domain is bought from Namecheap and point to Cloudflare. So I add the api A record in Cloudflare DNS.

1. DNS only mode

   ```
   http://api.domain.com:4000/graphql - it is working(I can query the data). 
   https://api.domain.com:4000/graphql - it is not working.
   ```
2. Proxied mode

   ```
   https://api.domain.com:4000/graphql - time out.   
   https://api.domain.com/graphql - ssl is working but could not reach 
   to hosting server.
   ```

How can I configure to work https://api.domain.com/graphql
ssl without port no.

Cloudflare said that calling with port number is not working in Proxied mode.

Answer (score 1):

On Cloudflare, port `4000` can be used to proxy traffic (such as `https` requests) when configured as a [Cloudflare Spectrum](https://developers.cloudflare.com/spectrum/get-started) application.

The standard ports that are supported (without requiring Spectrum) are [listed here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/network-ports#network-ports-compatible-with-cloudflares-proxy).

Alternatively, you could change the configured port of your own service from `4000` to one of the supported ports from the above link.

Comment: thanks for comment. My plan is free. So spectrum config is no option. I will change the port that supported or will create a nginx reverse proxy server to redirect base on sub domain